# LibGDX FreeTypeFont Outline and Drop Shadow?

Tags: java, libgdx, freetype, outline, dropshadow

This may be a long shot, but does anyone happen to know if there is a way to add an outline and a drop shadow to a FreeTypeFont in LibGDX? I've done quite a bit of research but there's not much information on this topic. I did find this on github which looks like it would do exactly what I want, but it doesn’t appear that it was finished.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/2191

I also tried asking on the LibGDX forum, but didn't get any responses. So it seems like there may not currently be a way to do this, but I thought I'd ask just in case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: rinold started a new pull and finished the outline and drop shadow feature. It has now been merged into LibGDX, I just tested it out and it works perfectly!
Here is the link:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/2774

Comment: is this something that you can dynamically do when running the game, or is it a pre-rendered effect?

Comment: Yes, it is done while the game is running. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype

Answer (score 2):

You can simply draw the text in black, then draw in color with a small offset, producing a shadow appearance. See the link [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/2191) for an image that conveys what I am trying to say. In addition, I think LibGDX has added shadow support internally as evidenced by the link.

Comment: Thanks for responding Malik. I did try a similar work around, but ran into problems with the outline. I tried using a black font and a slightly smaller white font to set inside of the black font, but I could not change the spacing (or padding) between the white characters to make them line up with the black font.

Comment: Use the same font size. Draw the black text at `(x, y)` and the white text at `(x + 6, y + 6)`. This will allow for a 6 pixel offset. Be sure to use the same font size.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you edited your comment and added more. The link you posted is the same one that I posted in my question. That is something that someone was working on, but it doesn't sound like it was completed or added to LibGDX. So based on that it seems these features may not be available in LibGDX yet (I kind of figured this was a long shot). Hopefully someone will be able to finish that outline and drop shadow project. I looked at the source code and it was over my head to be able to help with. :(

Comment: Use the same font size. Draw the black text at `(x, y)` and the white text at `(x + 6, y + 6)`. This will allow for a 6 pixel offset. Be sure to use the same font size. Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks Malik. I did get the drop shadow working using the same font size with an x,y offset. But one of the problems I ran into was with a black outline around the entire font. Like this: http://img.font.downloadatoz.com/download/imgs/s/w/i/swiss-721-black-outline-bt-upper.png

There the white font would need to be smaller to set "inside" of the black font. The other problem I ran into was I wanted to be able to set a transparency on the font which was impossible when layering texts on top of each other. So I was hoping there was a way to add these effects directly to the font. Thanks again.

Comment: Draw four black texts at `(x+6, y+6)` and `(x+6, y-6)` and `(x-6, y+6)` and `(x-6, y-6)`. Then draw the white text at `(x, y)`. Make sure they are all the same size.

Comment: Thanks Malik. I did have that thought as well and did some tests in MS Paint but it looked kind of funky. From my test it would take more than 4 to keep rounded letters from flattening out in certain spots. Plus I still had the problem of not being able to make the text slightly transparent since the border and drop shadow would show through the main text. I've spent a while on this problem trying to think of various ways to make it work and it's proving to be more complicated than expected. I may end up having to wait and see if someone finishes the outline and shadow project. Thanks again!

Comment: Couldn't you perhaps find a font with a border, so that you won't have to worry about it yourself?

Comment: Malik, that is where I started out. I searched through pages and pages of Truetype fonts with black borders and none of them were anything I wanted. Then I thought it might actually be better to have control over the text effects (thickness of the border, position of the drop shadow, etc) because the text is mainly going to be for UI components (buttons and such), so I started looking into how to add it in LibGDX. I certainly didn't think it would be such a difficult task, as text effects are usually pretty standard features...man was I wrong! lol Thanks for all your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Just be sure to mark as answer. Help me to help you, you know?

Comment: I just marked your response as helpful. :) My question not completely answered, so I would like to leave it open in case anyone happens to know of a way that we've been missing.